# Convert File object to URI object where the path contains spaces

Tags: java

In my program I have the conversion as illustrated by the test. 
Path->File->URI->URL->File.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class UrlStuffTest {

    @Test
    public void testFileToUriToUrlWithCreateFile() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get("testfolder", "xmls");
        File f = p.toAbsolutePath().toFile();
        f.mkdirs();
        System.out.println(f);
        URI uri = f.toURI();
        System.out.println(uri);
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        System.out.println(url);
        File aXmlFile = new File(url.getPath(), "test.xml");
        System.out.println(aXmlFile);
        aXmlFile.createNewFile();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFileToUriToUrlWithCreateFileAndSpaceInPath() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get("test folder", "xmls");
        File f = p.toAbsolutePath().toFile();
        f.mkdirs();
        System.out.println(f);
        URI uri = f.toURI();
        System.out.println(uri);
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        System.out.println(url);
        File aXmlFile = new File(url.getPath(), "test.xml");
        System.out.println(aXmlFile);
        aXmlFile.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

If you run the methods you will see that the upper one succeeds. The last one has a space in the path and fails on the last line basically saying *"System can not find path..."*.

Output of the first method is

> C:\Development\Workspace\spielwiese\testfolder\xmls
>   file:/C:/Development/Workspace/spielwiese/testfolder/xmls/
>   file:/C:/Development/Workspace/spielwiese/testfolder/xmls/
>   C:\Development\Workspace\spielwiese\testfolder\xmls\test.xml

Output of the second method is

> C:\Development\Workspace\spielwiese\test folder\xmls
>   file:/C:/Development/Workspace/spielwiese/test%20folder/xmls/
>   file:/C:/Development/Workspace/spielwiese/test%20folder/xmls/
>   C:\Development\Workspace\spielwiese\test%20folder\xmls\test.xml

So when converting from File to URI the space becomes a **%20**. I guess this is what makes the final XML file creation fail.

I solved this issue in my program by skipping the conversion from File to URI by using `File.toURL()` method. This method is deprecated though.

What would be a better solution?

Comment: `.replace("%20"," ")`?

Comment: `p.toUri()` is the correct way to convert a Path to a URI.  `f.toURI()` is the correct way to convert a File to a URI.  Is is normal and correct for a space to be represented as `%20`.  Literal space characters are not legal in a URI and must be percent-escaped.  Do you really care about URIs, or do you just want to create a Path that represents a child of a particular directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the `URL` string before using it as `File` path. Something like this

```
String decodedUrlPath = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Answer (score -1):

Really weird. With Path-File and without URL/URI it runs fine. Was trying to find other hints, but stuck on this one also:

```
Path path = Paths.get("test folder\\xmls", "test1.xml");
File aXmlFile = path.toFile();
System.out.println(aXmlFile);
aXmlFile.createNewFile();
```

So I guess in your URI you have to replace %20 pack to spaces " ".

Answer (score -1):

That code works:

```
aXmlFile = new File(url.getPath().replaceAll("%20", " "), "test.xml");

System.out.println(aXmlFile);
aXmlFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Not sufficient.  What do you think `Paths.get("piñata").toUri()` returns?

Comment: Works perfectly for me and creates piñata.xml file.

Comment: I wasn’t asking about piñata.xml.  I was asking what happens if `url` is created using `Paths.get("test folder", "piñata").toUri().toURL()`.